# Ошибка запуска эмулятора

Tags: windows, android-sdk, android

Система Windows Vista. Виртуальное устройство успешно создается, а когда запускается вываливается ошибка:

> `PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\РЈРїСЂР°РІР»СЏСЋС‰РёР№\.android\avd\z.avd/config.ini`

В чем причина и как исправить?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Проблема из-за кириллицы в пути. Надо переместить образ в корень и все ок. В файле `C:\Users\{Пользователь}\.android\avd\{Устройство}` изменить строку path так

> `path=D:\{Устройство}`

чтобы не было кириллицы в пути. И положить в новое место из старого образ устройства.